# compare to list of string without order in python

Tags: python, list, compare

I have a list of files like:

```
list1 = ['z.txt','x.txt','c.txt',.....'p.txt']
```

and then the script (with doing some work) will create a list of files of `list1` without order
I want to compare this two with `==` but because the `list2` is not in order of `list1` the script doesn't do anything
how can I compare this two list?

Comment: sort list by name ? or create a hash table

Comment: What is ```list2``` ? What are its contents ?

Comment: try using set ``intersection``, 
eg: ``"Match" if set(list1).intersection(list2) else "No Match"``

Comment: What is ```list2```

Comment: You should clarify the expected output giving an example of `list2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this

```
def all_elements_match(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False
    return all([e in list2 for e in list1])
```